# WordPress: page Template Conditional checking not working in functions.php

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to add a stylesheet in WordPress only if a user is using a specific template but conditional page template ( is_page_template('templa_name) ) is not working and code is falling into the else part. I have even gotten the right name of the template through code and tried adding that code but it didn't work. I can easily add and continue my development but it is strange and would like to know the solution to this weird problem.

Tried the code inside the template file and stackoverflow. there is an anwer but to no avail. Tried different variets of the code but it goes the same way

```
if ( is_page_template('page-templates/page-landing-page.php') ) {

    function this_echoes() {

        $looking_at = is_page_template( 'page-templates/page-landing-page.php' );
        echo $looking_at;
        echo '<br>';
        echo 'if';
        echo '<br>';
        $page_template22 = get_page_template_slug( get_queried_object_id() );
        echo $page_template22;
    }
     } else {
     function this_echoes() {

        $looking_at = is_page_template( 'page-templates/page-landing-page.php' );
        echo '<br>';
        echo $looking_at;
        echo '<br>';
        echo '$looking_at';
        echo '<br>';
        $page_template22 = get_page_template_slug( get_queried_object_id() );
        echo $page_template22 ;

        echo 'else';
      }

}
```

I want the code to fall under the if statement rather then else statement. I do know that I am checking the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition needs to go in the main this_echoes function.

I would suggest using template name slugs
(https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_template_slug) and then using an if check get your job done